# Nooby question for a splash screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

Trying to make a splash screen for my react native app using this guide: https://medium.com/@appstud/add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-810492e773f9
Trying to type this code in: [Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPQhr.png)

and I'm getting errors. Could someone please explain what the "create:" and "inputs:" mean and why they're grayed out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the explanation of the code parts. You put the inputs where it says inputs. Create is the block that you put your code that you want effect to trigger. You can read the documentation about the react hooks so you will have a better grasp before you try to jump into using them; [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)